# Is there any ORM Framework which maps in another way than ActiveRecord pattern says?

Tags: database, orm, ado.net

There is commonly used method to map object to table (one object - one row in a table; the table is corresponding to object type), i.e., each object's public field is mapped to corresponding column in a table. Most of the ORM Frameworks are based on that mapping method. The question is there any ORM Framework (based on .Net Framework and well suited for C#) which allows to map object onto several rows in a table where each object's field is mapped to corresponding table's row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say for all ORM Frameworks existing for today. But mapping in a following way:

(1) class type - table,
  (2) class member/field - column of the table,
  (3) class instance - row in a table,

is the well known practice. So, the more probable answer is there is no such ORM which maps a particular class instance on several rows. Otherwise, in accord with (2) the class type must has several members/fields represented with the same name but this is hardly possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an ORM that generates Collection objects for each of your tables.

Look into [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/)

Any query that returns more than 1 row returns a TableObjectCollection object that has multiple convenient methods for access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've walked through provided link. Unfortunately, I did not noted in the question that we need such an ORM Framework that well suited for C# .Net and the Propel ORM is only for PHP. But I've fixed the question already.